# r Replace only some table values with values from alternate table

Tags: r, vlookup, replacewith

This is not a "vlookup-and-fill-down" question.

My source data is excellent at delivering all the data I need, just not in in a usable form.  Recent changes in volume mean manually adjusted fixes are no longer feasible.

I have an inventory table and a services table. The inventory report does not contain purchase order data for services or non-inventory items. The services table (naturally) does. They are of course different shapes.

Pseudo-coding would be something to the effect of `for every inventory$Item in services$Item, replace inventory$onPO with services$onPO`.

Sample Data

```
inv <- structure(list(Item = c("10100200", "10100201", "10100202", "10100203", 
"10100204", "10100205-A", "10100206", "10100207", "10100208", 
"10100209", "10100210"), onHand = c(600L, NA, 39L, 0L, NA, NA, 
40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), demand = c(3300L, NA, 40L, 40L, NA, NA, 
70L, 126L, 10L, 10L, 250L), onPO = c(2700L, NA, 1L, 40L, NA, 
NA, 30L, 126L, 10L, 10L, 250L)), .Names = c("Item", "onHand", 
"demand", "onPO"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

svc <- structure(list(Item = c("10100201", "10100204", "10100205-A"), 
    `Rcv'd` = c(0L, 0L, 44L), Backordered = c(20L, 100L, 18L)), .Names = c("Item", 
"Rcv'd", "Backordered"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace `NA`s in `onPO` with values from `Backordered` here is a solution using `dplyr::left_join`:

```
library(dplyr);
left_join(inv, svc) %>%
    mutate(onPO = ifelse(is.na(onPO), Backordered, onPO)) %>%
    select(-Backordered, -`Rcv'd`);
#         Item onHand demand onPO
#1    10100200    600   3300 2700
#2    10100201     NA     NA   20
#3    10100202     39     40    1
#4    10100203      0     40   40
#5    10100204     NA     NA  100
#6  10100205-A     NA     NA   18
#7    10100206     40     70   30
#8    10100207      0    126  126
#9    10100208      0     10   10
#10   10100209      0     10   10
#11   10100210      0    250  250
```

Or a solution in base R using `merge`:

```
inv$onPO <- with(merge(inv, svc, all.x = TRUE), ifelse(is.na(onPO), Backordered, onPO))
```

---

Or using `coalesce` instead of `ifelse` (thanks to @thelatemail):

```
library(dplyr);
left_join(inv, svc) %>%
    mutate(onPO = coalesce(onPO, Backordered)) %>%
    select(-Backordered, -`Rcv'd`);
```

Comment: You could also use `coalesce` instead of the `ifelse` i think.

Comment: Thanks for the multitude of methods Maurits Evers and @thelatemail 
It's interesting that I could not find an answer via DuckDuckGo-ing around SO. Looking for the wrong terms I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` world, this is an "update-join". Join on "Item" and then update the values in the original set with the values from the new set:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(inv)
setDT(svc)

inv[svc, on="Item", c("onPO","onHand") := .(i.Backordered, `i.Rcv'd`)]

#inv   original table
#svc   update table
#on=   match on specified variable
# :=   overwrite  onPO    with  Backordered
#                 onHand  with  Rcv'd


#          Item onHand demand onPO
# 1:   10100200    600   3300 2700
# 2:   10100201      0     NA   20
# 3:   10100202     39     40    1
# 4:   10100203      0     40   40
# 5:   10100204      0     NA  100
# 6: 10100205-A     44     NA   18
# 7:   10100206     40     70   30
# 8:   10100207      0    126  126
# 9:   10100208      0     10   10
#10:   10100209      0     10   10
#11:   10100210      0    250  250
```

Comment: @rawr - i'm a big fan of data.table. I didn't think I'd be disappointing anybody :-P

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the tables:

```
  >inv
          Item OnHand Demand OnPO
 1:   10100200    600   3300 2700
 2:   10100201     NA     NA   NA
 3:   10100202     39     40    1
 4:   10100203      0     40   40
 5:   10100204     NA     NA   NA
 6: 10100205-A     NA     NA   NA
 7:   10100206     40     70   30
 8:   10100207      0    126  126
 9:   10100208      0     10   10
10:   10100209      0     10   10
11:   10100210      0    250  250

> svc
         Item Rcv'd Backordered
1:   10100201     0          20
2:   10100204     0         100
3: 10100205-A    44          18
```

After far more cursing than I'd like to admit, the simple solution that works on the above test data, and my live data proved to be:

```
# Insert OnHand and OnPO data from svc
for (i in 1:nrow(inv)) {
  if(inv$Item[i] %in% svc$Item) {
    x <- which(svc$Item == inv$Item[i])
    inv$OnPO[i] <- svc$Backordered[x]
    inv$OnHand[i] <- svc$`Rcv'd`[x]
  } 
    else{}
}
# cleanup 
inv[is.na(inv)] <- 0
```

Is there a simpler or more obvious method that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `eat` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and "patch"
the matches from the rhs into the lhs when columns conflict.

We rename `Backordered` to `onPO` on the way so the two columns conflict as desired.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

eat(inv, svc, onPO = Backordered, .conflict = "patch")
#          Item onHand demand onPO
# 1    10100200    600   3300 2700
# 2    10100201     NA     NA   20
# 3    10100202     39     40    1
# 4    10100203      0     40   40
# 5    10100204     NA     NA  100
# 6  10100205-A     NA     NA   18
# 7    10100206     40     70   30
# 8    10100207      0    126  126
# 9    10100208      0     10   10
# 10   10100209      0     10   10
# 11   10100210      0    250  250
```