# Modify part of data frame based on date

Tags: r

I have two dataset, and i would like to modify a section of one column. 
My first dataset has 4 column, date and variable Type A, B and C.

```
Main_df
Date    TypeA   TypeB   TypeC
1/1/2019    0   0   0
2/1/2019    0   0   0
3/1/2019    0   0   0
4/1/2019    0   100 0
5/1/2019    0   110 0
6/1/2019    0   120 0
7/1/2019    0   130 0
8/1/2019    0   140 0
9/1/2019    0   150 0
10/1/2019   100 0   0
11/1/2019   120 0   0
12/1/2019   130 0   0
```

The second has fewer rows and only one column, which in this case is called TypeB, and should be added to the current values of TypeB in the main dataset at the matching dates

```
df_i
Date    TypeB
2/1/2019    120
3/1/2019    130
4/1/2019    140
5/1/2019    150
```

The result should look like this :

```
Main_df
Date    TypeA   TypeB   TypeC
1/1/2019    0   0   0
2/1/2019    0   120 0
3/1/2019    0   130 0
4/1/2019    0   240 0
5/1/2019    0   260 0
6/1/2019    0   120 0
7/1/2019    0   130 0
8/1/2019    0   140 0
9/1/2019    0   150 0
10/1/2019   100 0   0
11/1/2019   120 0   0
12/1/2019   130 0   0
```

I know how to modify the entire column, but not just a section, especially not when it has to match a date. but i would be surprise if R cannot do that. Can someone help please ?

Comment: Lots of similar discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374306/r-replace-only-some-table-values-with-values-from-alternate-table/49374410

Comment: Doesn't matter for this question, but you should parse your dates into date objects, e.g. with `as.Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` one way would be to bind the two dataframes together which would give `NA` for non-matching columns, `group_by` `Date` and take `sum` removing `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(Main_df, df1) %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(TypeA:TypeC), sum, na.rm = TRUE)


# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   Date      TypeA TypeB TypeC
#   <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
# 1 1/1/2019      0     0     0
# 2 10/1/2019   100     0     0
# 3 11/1/2019   120     0     0
# 4 12/1/2019   130     0     0
# 5 2/1/2019      0   120     0
# 6 3/1/2019      0   130     0
# 7 4/1/2019      0   240     0
# 8 5/1/2019      0   260     0
# 9 6/1/2019      0   120     0
#10 7/1/2019      0   130     0
#11 8/1/2019      0   140     0
#12 9/1/2019      0   150     0
```